# Unique validation not working on module wise configuration YII2

Tags: yii2

I am using yii2 and application is in module configuration. Now I am trying to apply unique validation on multiple columns but it shows error.

I've written rule for it in model

```
[['group_name', 'menu_name', 'screen_name'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['screen_name', 'group_name']]
```

It should work if we get record with given values in all columns that is defined in rule but for not it shows error 'Call to undefined method app\modules\admin\models\forms\GroupScreenForm::getDb()'. Please help.

Comment: `unique` rule requires database connection to check if record is unique - your form model needs to provide this connection via `getDb()`. Your form model should probably extend `ActiveRecord` to use this rule in convenient way.